# Drawing a straight line graph and estimating the values of 2 constants.

Tags: geometry, estimation

This question is from an exam paper for the Merchant Navy but the questions are similar to those found in A Level Maths so I hope this is in the right place.

5. Variables P and V are thought to be related by a law of the form: $PV^n=C$ where n and C are constants.

Observations of P and V are recorded below:

P=15, V=4.42

P=20, V=3.55

P=30, V=2.60

P=40, V=2.06

P=50, V=1.74

Suggested scales: 2cm=0.1 
(I've used Desmos to plot the points anyway)

Part (a) Draw a straight line graph to verify this relationship.
Part (b) Use the graph drawn in (a) to estimate the values of n and C.

My attempts:

(a) [Graph of the plotted points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4O8l.png)

First of all, this isn't a straight line graph so that's totally thrown me. Even if you plot it on paper you won't get the straight line graph it wants you to get?

(b) I can rearrange $PV^n = C$ to $P=\frac{C}{V^n}$ but not sure how to estimate the values from that or the graph. It's going to be a reciprocal graph, but how do you estimate the values of C or n? My best guess is that n=1 and C=80 using Desmos to plot the graphs.

Any form of guidance is most helpful.

Comment: Hint: first use logarithms to transform your data into a form where a straight line fits.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent a while trying different things but I've got a graph that matches the points now.

Comment: How do you know to log both sets of data? @Théophile I'm trying the same question with a different equation but not sure how to get the data to fit a straight line again.

Comment: It can take a bit of experience or trial and error. The key here is to notice that taking the log of both sides of your equation will bring down the exponent and turn the multiplicative relationship between $P$ and $V$ into an additive relationship between $\log P$ and $\log V$. That is, $\log P + n\log V = \log C$.

Comment: So for your new question, try manipulating the equation somehow. If you take the log of both sides, what happens this time? Or maybe you need to do some other operation.